# What is the correct way to perform TestCafe assertions

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I am basically stuck between a rock and sort of a hard place. I’m writing some automation scripts using TestCafe and I need some help on best practices. Basically I would like to know the best way to create an assertion that waits a brief period of time until an element appears before executing.

My Current implementation:

```js
const setTimeout = 5000;

await t
    .expect(this.papernote.exists, { timeout: setTimeout })
    .ok('The trail is not visible');
```

When the test executes, it seems like the timeout does not get respected. Meaning TestCafe will wait the default time (3 seconds I believe) then the assertion will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to define a timeout for a particular assertion, pass the options object to the `ok` method:

```
await t
    .expect(this.papernote.exists)
    .ok('The trail is not visible', { timeout: setTimeout });
```

See the documentation article for details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html#ok

Comment: Sweeet. Thanks for the advice. This seems to be working much better.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you want to increase the selector timeout. Try using this flag

```
--selector-timeout 500000
```

and you can also try

```
--assertion-timeout 10000
```

or you can try waiting for the element,

```
await element.with({ visibilityCheck: true }).with({timeout: 10000});
```

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html